# WordPress Date Archives not working in Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, wordpress, httpd.conf, ngx-http-rewrite-module

WordPress installed in a subdirectory:

```
domain.com/folder
```

WordPress Permalink Settings:

```
domain.com/folder/%postname%
```

Referencing the [WordPress Nginx support article](https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/), I added the following to my nginx config:

```
location /folder {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /folder/index.php?$args;
}
```

Permalinks for pages, posts, authors, categories, and tags work great.

Permalinks for date archives do not work.

For example, when I hover the mouse over August 2021, it shows the following link:

```
domain.com/folder/2021/08
```

But instead of going to the appropriate date archive, it instead goes to:

```
domain.com/folder
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the [example wordpress config from nginx.com](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/)?

Comment: Please show the output of `nginx -T`